# Sumo Logic: Structured Logging Support?

Tags: sumologic, structured-logging

Does Sumo Logic support structured logging (.ie message templates, message template hashing, property mapping, etc)?  This is supported by Seq and Splunk, but so far all I see is the ability to log as JSON and use the json pipe to manipulate it...

Comment: Supposedly: https://www.sumologic.com/glossary/structured-logging/